# How to make IIS URL rewrite precede my web app?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, arr

Goal: I want to host the following:

- `/docs` should be proxied to `remote-server:443`
- `*` should be served by my ASP.NET web app

I have installed the following:

- [ARR](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)
- [IIS URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

My IIS Server has the following `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config`:

```
...xml
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
            <globalRules>
                <rule name="My Rewrite Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^docs(/.*)?" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://remote-server/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </globalRules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
...
```

Expected: All calls to `/docs` should proxy to `remote-server` and stop all processing.

Actual: I navigate to `https://localhost/docs` and am redirected to my ASP.NET web app's login page.

Comment: Did you open a private tab of your web browser? Keep in mind that a normal tab caches previous redirection responses, so what you observe there can be wrong.

Comment: Have you made a '301' request to /docs before? If so, subsequent requests to /docs will bypass the web server, the browser will check its cache and read that the URL was '301' before, and redirected without even checking for changes. 301 is a normal cacheable response code. If you don't want caching, your server needs to indicate that via the normal headers that control caching behavior, and you can also clear the cache manually. Another quick fix is to use a private browser window.

Comment: I tested the path in a private window and am still getting redirected. This rules out 301 HTTP header/browser cache behaviour.

Comment: Do you have any other redirect rules set up on your site?